# Moving from sublime to vim, html indentation issues

Tags: html, vim

So I recently made the switch from sublime to vim and i'm already really loving the VIM workflow. However, I'm having some trouble getting my VIM html indentation to resemble sublime's html indentation.

Basically every tab from my old code is "double tabbed", and in many places where sublime had a line break, vim does not. Here are my vimrc indenation settings:

```
set expandtab       " use spaces instead of tabs
set autoindent      " autoindent based on line above, works most of the time
set smartindent     " smarter indent for C-like languages
set shiftwidth=4    " when reading, tabs are 4 spaces
set softtabstop=4   " in insert mode, tabs are 4 spaces
```

And in sublime I'm using Tab Size: 4, which I believe should be the equivalent.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your .vimrc file:

```
set tabstop=4
```

Comment: You are welcome! If you find my answer helpful, would you mark it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your .vimrc file:

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set noexpandtab
```